# Continuous non-piecewise equivalent of smoothstep function?

Tags: functions, interpolation, polynomials, trigonometry, piecewise

I have a smooth step function given by the piecewise function

```
smoothstep[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, x <= -(1/2)}, 
   {-20*(x + 1/2)^7 + 70*(x + 1/2)^6 - 84*(x + 1/2)^5 + 
       35*(x + 1/2)^4, -(1/2) < x < 1/2}, {1, x >= 1/2}}]
Plot[smoothstep[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I'd very much like to find a non-piecewise expression for this - i.e., a single algebraic expression (which I realise will likely contain infinities).

Is it possible to use Mathematica to find such an expression? I tried obtaining an approximation with

```
interp = InterpolatingPolynomial[{{-10, 0}, 
   {-9, 0, 0}*{-8, 0, 0}, {-7, 0, 0}*{-6, 0, 0}, {-5, 0, 0}, 
   {-4, 0, 0}, {-3, 0, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2}, 
   {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 1, 0}, {5, 1, 0}, 
   {6, 1, 0}, {7, 1, 0}, {8, 1, 0}, {9, 1, 0}, {10, 1, 0}}, x]
```

but it produces a nonsense-plot:

[image]

Suggestions? Or can it simply not be done?

**UPDATE**

Both @Michael and @Thies provide excellent answers below. I have ticked @Michael's because it is more comprehensive, but both are correct and useful.

Comment: Looks like a [logistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

Comment: the difference is that logistic curves *tend* towards `0` and `1` rather than actually reaching those values at a specified value of `x` - hence the fact that the smooth step is piecewise...

Comment: How smooth do you want your curve to be? How many derivatives should be continuous? Can you have a curve that is not piecewise but is actually equal to 0 and 1 away from the step?

Comment: Ideally infinitely differentiable, and about as smooth as the piecewise`smoothstep` function I gave in the OP. It doesn't have to *be* that curve, though... And I don't know the answer to whether it's possible. That's the main reason I'm asking the question! Thanks for your thought and input.

Comment: I think you want a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), a function with compact support that is infinitely differentiable. Even more suiting seems to be a [smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) or [Mollified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) version of a unit step. The article about smooth functions also has an example of a smooth unit step. I can write an answer if you need more details.

Comment: Do you just need it over that interval? Fourier Transform with truncated terms? Otherwise not seeing an expression that doesn't contain an 'if-then' construct. But if it's differentiability you need, then the bump function can hopefully scratch the itch.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll do some more homework!

Comment: Hi @Thies, I appreciate your work on this. I can’t mark it as answered because I was hoping for a non-piecewise solution. I’ll look into the bump and smooth functions, though. And once again, thanks.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward I see what you mean, no worries. But i think it's important to notice that there is an intrinsic reason or relationship between a function being infinitely often differentiable while still having compact support and being non-analytic. The article about [flat functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) explains this quite well by saying, they are kind of the antithesis to analytic functions, which are also infinitely differentiable but with infinite support. They are kind of mutually exclusive. (1/2)

Comment: Now the interesting question is: Can there be an algebraic function (to not be defined piecewise), that is a bump/test function with the compact support you want, but without being analytic (because that wouldn't allow for compact support)? Interesting would also be what is the original problem is that you are trying to solve? Maybe there are other ways to get the properties you want. (2/2)

Comment: I'll look into these, but it might take me a few days. You asked what I'm aiming to achieve. I'm trying to experiment with the idea of tying the integrals of something like a bump function centred on successive values of `x` (i.e., a set of non-piecewise, non-asymptotic sigmoids with centres at `x={0,1,2,3,4...}`) to some other function that yields a narrow range of values (the Möbius function, for example). The idea is be to create a composite function that creates a continuous curve that sums the Möbius function from `0` to `x` for integer `x`, but is a continuous curve. Experimental. Fun!

Comment: This reminds me of my digital (discrete times controls course taken last century, where you can design a system with *deadbeat* response, i.e., a finite settling time. Might be worth a google for inspiration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an "algebraic expression" using the same sort of smooth ($C^\infty$) transition function as @Thies's:

```
Plot[
 1/4 (2 + (-2 + 4 x)/
     Sqrt[(1 - 2 x)^2] + ((1 + 
         Sqrt[(-1 + 2 x)^2]/(1 - 2 x)) (1 + (1 + 2 x)/
          Sqrt[(1 + 2 x)^2]))/(1 + E^((8 x)/(-1 + 4 x^2)))),
 {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Like @Thies's, it's not *Mathematica*-lly differentiable at the points where the function transitions to a constant, even though it is mathematically infinitely differentiable there.  This is due to the way derivatives of `Piecewise[]` are handled in @Thies's and because mine has a divide-by-zero error.

---

**Addendum.**
The only way I've figured out how to get a function that *Mathematica* will yield a symbolic derivative at the transition points is by overriding the differentiation operator.  To make it numerically and symbolically efficient requires some work:

```
ClearAll[smoothstep,
  ss0, dss, idss,(* internal aux fns (smoothstep, derivative, internal derivative *)
  smoothstepExpand];
Block[{x},   (* because x is evaluated in some definitions *)
 ss0[x_] := 1/(1 + Exp[2/(2 x + 1) - 2/(1 - 2 x)]);  (* base expression *)
 dss[0, x_] = Piecewise[{  (* complete base function *)
    {ss0[x], -1/2 < x < 1/2},
    {1, x >= 1/2}}];
 smoothstep[x_?NumericQ] = dss[0, x];  (* function, limited to eval on numerical input *)
 (* idss[n,x] is the general n-th derivative, which has the form of an 
    inactivated Sum[] in terms of a DifferenceRoot[];
    idss[] is numerically unstable near x==1/2, but when simplified, behaves better;
    hence in dss[] below, which calls idss[], one sees Simplify@Activate@idss[n,y] *)
 idss[n_, x_] = Piecewise[{{D[ss0[x], {x, n}], -1/2 < x < 1/2}}];
 dss[n_, x_] := Block[{y},  (* called internally for a specific positive integer n *)
   dss[n, y_] = Simplify@Activate@idss[n, y]; (* memoize simplified symbolic derivative *)
   dss[n, x]];
 Derivative[n_Integer?Positive][smoothstep][x_?NumericQ] :=
   dss[n, x];  (* evaluate derivative at numeric input *)
 smoothstepExpand[expr_] := 
  expr /. {  (* expand smoothstep[], smoothstep'[] etc. into Piecewise expressions *)
    HoldPattern[smoothstep[x_]] :> dss[0, x],
    HoldPattern[Derivative[n_Integer?Positive][smoothstep][x0_]] :> 
     dss[n, x0]}
 ]

Plot[
 {smoothstep[x], smoothstep'[x]},
 {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: For any interested, I think the core of this expression is basically `1/(1+E^(1/(a-1)+1/a))`.

Answer (score 8):

You want a [smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) or [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function), a function with compact support which is infinitely differentiable. An example for a smooth unit step given in the Wikipedia article is

```
f[x_] := Boole[x > 0] Exp[-1/x]
g[x_] := f[x] / (f[x] + f[1-x])

Plot[g[x], {x, -0.1, 1.1}]
```

[image: smooth step]

An equivalent definition is

```
g[x]//PiecewiseExpand//FullSimplify

Piecewise[{
  {0, x <= 0},
  {1/(1+Exp[1/x - 1/(1-x)]), 0 < x < 1},
  {1, True}}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know know if you like this any better, but I'm not sure what you have against `Piecewise`.  You can convert to `UnitStep` with:

```
smoothstep[x_] =  Simplify`PWToUnitStep@ Piecewise[{{0, 
     x <= -(1/2)}, {-20*(x + 1/2)^7 + 70*(x + 1/2)^6 - 
      84*(x + 1/2)^5 + 35*(x + 1/2)^4, -(1/2) < x < 1/2}, {1,  x >= 1/2}}]
(*1/16 (-(320 x^7) + 336 x^5 - 140 x^3 + 35 x + 8) (1 -  UnitStep[-x - 1/2]) (1 - UnitStep[x - 1/2]) + UnitStep[x - 1/2]*)
```

The plots of the function and its derivatives look the same as original.

Comment: I'd like to mark more than one answer as 'correct' - how do I do that?

Comment: I don't think that that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Tanh[x]`

```
Plot[{smoothstep[x], (1 + Tanh[x 5])/2}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich but this is asymptotic again...